# The file was not uploaded in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ajax

I'm trying to save the attachment file in my custom module using `$.ajax({})` request. But it's not working for me. For these, I tried the below code.

In cart page having below code.

```
<dl class="item-options">
    <dt>
        <span>Add File to Item</span>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <?php
            $uName = "itemUploadFile_" . $itemId . "_" . "[]";
            $id = "upload_" . $quote_id . "_" . $itemId;
        ?>
        <input id="<?php echo $id; ?>"  name="<?php echo $uName ?>" multiple="" type="file" class="input-text"/>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

And javascript code is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'domReady!'
    ], function ($) {
         $("#<?php echo $id ?>").change(function(e) {
            let itemId = "<?php echo $itemId ?>";
            let quote_id = "<?php echo $item->getQuoteId(); ?>";
            const _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png", ".pdf", ".doc", "docx"];
            //console.log(e.target.files[j]);
            if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
                for (let j=0; j< e.target.files.length; j++){
                    let fileEx = e.target.files[j].name.split(".");
                    let fileExtension = "." + fileEx[1];
                    if (_validFileExtensions.indexOf(fileExtension.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                        //let output = JSON.parse(e.target.files[j]);
                        //console.log(output);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'test/index/savefile' ?>",
                            method:'POST',
                            dataType:"json",
                            showLoader:true,
                            data: {quote_id: quote_id, quote_item_id: itemId,size: e.target.files[j].size,fileName: e.target.files[j].name},
                            success: function (response) {
                               console.log(response['result']);
                            },
                            error:function (jqXHR, exception) {
                                let msg = '';
                                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                                } else if (jqXHR.status === 404) {
                                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                                } else if (jqXHR.status === 500) {
                                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                                } else {
                                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                                }
                                console.log(msg);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert("Sorry, " + e.target.files[j].name + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
                        this.value = "";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I send file data using `e.target.files[j]` it's not working for me.

Can you please suggest us how can I send attachment file details to ajax request?

Comment: Please mention your error log here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my self by adding below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'domReady!'
    ], function($,){

         $("#<?php echo $id ?>").change(function(e) {
            let itemId = "<?php echo $itemId ?>";
            let quote_id = "<?php echo $item->getQuoteId(); ?>";
            const _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png", ".pdf", ".doc", "docx"];


            if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
                let countVal = e.target.files.length - 1;
                for ( let j=0; j< e.target.files.length; j++){
                    let fileEx = e.target.files[j].name.split(".");
                    let fileExtension = "." + fileEx[1];
                    if (_validFileExtensions.indexOf(fileExtension.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                        try{
                            if(countVal === j) {
                                let fd = new FormData();
                                //let names = [];
                                let file_data = $('#<?php echo $id ?>')[0].files;
                                for (let i = 0; i < file_data.length; i++) {
                                    fd.append("file[]", file_data[i]);
                                }
                                //fd.append('file[]', names);
                                fd.append('quote_id', quote_id);
                                fd.append('quote_item_id', itemId);

                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'test/index/savefile/' ?>',
                                    type: 'post',
                                    data: fd,
                                    contentType: false,
                                    processData: false,
                                    showLoader: true,
                                    success: function (response) {
                                        let data = $.parseJSON(response);
                                        alert(data.result);
                                    },
                                    error: function (response) {
                                        alert('error : ' + JSON.stringify(response));
                                        this.value = "";
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }catch(err) {
                            alert(err.message);
                            this.value = "";
                            return false;
                        }

                    } else {
                        alert("Sorry, " + e.target.files[j].name + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
                        this.value = "";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        $('body').on('click','.quotation_delete',function(e){
            let fileId = $(this).data("id");
            alert(fileId);
        });

    });

</script>
```